# Is there a difference between "to annihilate" and "to eradicate"?

Tags: word-difference

Both mean the same according to dictionaries (to destroy something ​completely), but what is the difference between the usage of these terms?

I've heard that annihilate can be used for cities and building but eradicate more for non-physical things. Is that really correct? How are these terms different for native speakers?

Answer (score 3):

Eradicate according to [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/eradicate) means:

> To remove or destroy utterly; extirpate:
>
> *To eradicate smallpox throughout the world.*

And the etymology of eradicate is *out root*, to pull up by the roots. So, *to eradicate* means to wipe out from the roots. This usage is usually for non-human items such as *small pox* in the example given.

Annihilate according to [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/annihilate),  means:

> 1. To reduce to utter ruin or nonexistence; destroy utterly:
>
> *The heavy bombing almost annihilated the city.*
>
> 2. To destroy the collective existence or main body of; wipe out:
>
> *To annihilate an army.*

The etymology of this word is *to nothing*. *To annihilate* is to wipe out something to nothing. This usage from what I have seen, is usually for human related things such as *army* and *city* in the examples I have given.

Comment: Thanks . how about ideologies? For example  "We will annihilate / eradicate absolutism / communism / fascism in this country"

Comment: "Eradicate" for ideologies. "Eradicate" for me always has a sense of "move" or "move out", as in "expel" or "banish", possibly only from a certain area, whereas "annihilate" means complete elimination (nihil), to zero, everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

## Short Answer

> - Use **annihilate** when the objects are **human** (or human-related, like cities or buildings).
> - Use **eradicate** when the objects are **non-human** (like pests or diseases).

I don't think this distinction is in the dictionary. However, that nuance in usage has been my experience as a native speaker.